# liferay 6.2 web content options ready only mode. how to configure liferay control panel to display web the web content?

Tags: liferay

I'm unable to create the web content in liferay 6.2 assuming some configuration required for the same. Not able to enter any value in textboxes and none of the links working. I'm new to liferay please help me out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa86t.jpg)

Comment: This is offtopic for stackoverflow. SO is mainly for programming related issues. You might get better help on the forums at https://liferay.com/community. The setup that you're posting the screenshot of *should* work - check the browsers error console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely have a Javascript error in your page that block the complete front-end interface funcionalities. You should check the browser console to find this errors.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks atrujillofalcon. Yes, There is some issue with ckeditor which not allowing to display the complete ui page. ckeditor plugin needs to be updated to resolve the issue.